# Setting label from node properties

Tags: neo4j

I created >100 nodes with properties, that were meant to be labels. 
Each node looks like this

```
{
  "name": "Cow",
  "type": "Animal"
}
```

Can i do something like this below?

```
match (n)
set n :n.type
return n
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only by adding APOC library to Neo4j.
That is done by placing the library jar in the Neo4j's plugins folder.
If neo4j is run using docker, add the jar to `/plugins`.
You will also need to set an env variable.

```
NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=apoc.*
```

Ref: https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-apoc/

Then you can use `CALL apoc.create.addLabels` to add labels.

```
MATCH (n)
CALL apoc.create.addLabels(n, [n.type])
YIELD node
RETURN node;
```

Ref: https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-updates/data-creation/

I created two nodes to test this:

```
CREATE ({name:"Cow", type:"Animal"});
CREATE ({name:"Whale", type:"Fish"});
```

I was then able to apply labels using APOC query above.